# Paypal Adaptive Chained payment with Recurring Payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, recurring-billing

I have already set-up the chained adaptive payment using adaptive paypal API for our website, but we need to have a recurring billing attached to this adaptive payment. IS there a way we can integrate adaptive payment with recurring billing?

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

The Adaptive Payments API doesn't have a recurring billing / subscription subscription in the traditional sense.  Instead, it uses Preapproval Profiles / Preapproved Payments.

You need to use the Preapproval API to create a profile for your payer(s), which returns a Preapproval Key.  Then you can include that Preapproval Key in Pay requests to trigger an instant payment without any further approval necessary...no redirect to PayPal would be required since the payment was already approved by the Preapproval Profile.

So with that preapproval key you can set your app up to process payments at whatever interval you need.